# adding subview problem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, addsubview

I am having the following problem while adding a subview to navigation controller. I even have tried to modify the Y location of frame before and after adding the subview but not effective.

Also tried to put a status bar on the child view but nothing is working.

[image: 20 pixels problem]

Many Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Please post some code of Your ViewContoller

Comment: @Dan F: The problem is the view is going 20 Px above the screen

Comment: @Adarsh V C: I am using this : myVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(myVC.view.frame.origin.x, myVC.view.frame.origin.y - 20,
               myVC.view.frame.size.width, myVC.view.frame.size.height);

    [APPDELEGATE.navigationController.view addSubview:myVC.view]; But this is not working

Comment: @Naveed - and you're replaced "y-20" with y?  Try 0, or 15 or something hardcoded in the CGRectMake to see if it responds.

Comment: @Mike: Yes I have tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much everyone of you. I don't know what was the issue but instead of adding subview now I am using pushViewController and I am pushing the viewcontroller to the parent navigation controller. This solved the issue.

Thank you all of you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with a fullScreen IB checkbox or a fullscreen property set programmaticaly. Don't you call somewhere something like viewController.setStatusBarVisible = NO. Check it, I had the same problem.

**EDIT :** Does those questions / anwers help ?

[iPhone - ModalViewController not raising to top of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333120/iphone-modalviewcontroller-not-raising-to-top-of-the-screen)

[iPhone - displaying NavigationBar on a fullscreen modalView makes it go down with transparent space on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362322/iphone-displaying-navigationbar-on-a-fullscreen-modalview-makes-it-go-down-with)

Comment: @Naveed Rafi : are you running the camera ?

Comment: No I am using simple UIViews, UIViewControllers