# UINavigationController space above navigation bar

Tags: ios

I have a UINavigationContorller which leads to a UITableView. The problem is that just above the UINavigationBar I have some white space. I think it is the status bar as it has the same saze, but I can't get how to remove it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate with many good answers :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393868/how-do-i-get-the-navigation-bar-in-a-uinavigationcontroller-to-update-its-positi

Comment: I think I didn't explain well myself, the status bar I want to hide is the one above the UItableView which is in a container view, not the actual bar at the top of the ipad screen

Comment: So you're not trying to hide the system status bar? It sounds like you want to hide a navigationBar from a previous viewcontroller? i.e., you have a NavController pushing to a containerview with a navcontroller inside?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:true];
```

in one of the view delegate method like viewDidLoad or viewWillappear method.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the status bar then you can do it by :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:true];
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the Project and Got to 'Targets' and in 'Summery' u can see the statusBar column. there c you can uncheck visibility check box 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XVLP.png