# Adding MKMapView Causes Status Bar Issue in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mkmapview, statusbar

I'm solving the status bar issue in iOS 7 using

```
if(st.version == 7)
{
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 20;
    frame.size.height = screen.size.height - 20;
    self.navigationController.view.frame = frame;
}
```

Since I'm using navigation controller and pushing from one to another using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newone animated:YES];`. It works fine in all view controllers. But, if the viewcontroller has mkmapview in xib, status bar issue of ios 7 occurs.

If I delete the mapview form xib and push to that view controller means, it will be like,

[image]

If I add the mapview even by code below,

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
```

It looks like,

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue in my macine can u provide some sample project in github. i will help to figure out the issue easily.

Comment: have you tried , clipsToBounds for mapview

Comment: which device is come either 3.5 and 4 inch or both

Comment: but your image is represented ios 6 back button style why

Comment: post your st.version checking code

Comment: why not use edgesForExtendedLayout for status bar issue fixing

Comment: Are you using `autolayout` ?

Comment: I just uncheck `useAutolayout` in xib and used `Autoresizing` for map and not getting this issue. I have fixed my map from top and left via `Autoresizing`.

Comment: First of all, I apologize for not mentioning that i used the `if(st.version == 7)...` code in viewWillAppear method. Roma's answer helped me to solve the issue. Upvotes for all answers. thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add mapView in `viewWillAppear` replace it in `viewDidAppear`.
Maybe you have this issue because you're doing manipulations with view's frames before your view is completely set up

Answer (score 2):

```
if(st.version == 7){

   mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 100)];

}else{

   mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100)];

}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, the issue is not related to mapview's frame.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

Comment: I want the view to look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zgyiw.png) after adding mapview. This answer  won't solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest against doing it like that.

If you're using interface builder, then add constraints based on how you want your application to look and the frame will auto adjust itself.

If you're not using interface builder, then still use constraints, but get a good tutorial about making constraints programatically (as I don't know how to do it myself).

Edit: The reason I HIGHLY suggest not doing it with hardcoded numbers is that it'll be a pain to do iOS 6/7 Landscape/Portrait 3.5/4 inch screens. That's 8 cases.

Comment: App has only one orientation and it also supports ios 5 where we can't use auto layout.

Comment: Zsolt, would you mind migrating this to a comment. I agree with Daij-Djan that this is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have some adjust your navigation Y position set -20px. that way it goes overlay. use this code your ViewController

```
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
frame.origin.y =0;
frame.size.height = screen.size.height;
self.navigationController.view.frame = frame;
```

or may it you have use wantFullScreenLayout some where in your project

```
setWantsFullScreenLayout = YES:
```

statusbar section is located to the (0,0) point to catch. 
Statusbar and as large as the size of the current view to increase the value of mainScreen change the size of the bounds. 
Statusbar change the style of the translucent style.

this below link you get some clear idea about your issue

[How do I get the navigation bar in a UINavigationController to update its position when the status bar is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393868/how-do-i-get-the-navigation-bar-in-a-uinavigationcontroller-to-update-its-positi)

Comment: wantsFullScreenLayout is deprecated in iOS 7

Comment: see the question image the problem in iOS6. watch the navigation back button you understand which version the problem raised. @Andy

Comment: No, I believe that the question image was captured in iOS 7. The back button in the navigation bar can be customised to iOS 6 style in iOS 7. But the status bar can't be customised to iOS 7 style in iOS 6.

Comment: please watch tabbar also it's look ios6 @lancy

Comment: if he using  black translucent in ios 6 it like above image @lancy

Comment: Sorry, unless the OP say himself that he hide the status bar and make a new one just the same as iOS 7 state bar, I still believe that is in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `-edgesForExtendedLayout` method in your view controller

```
-(UIRectEdge)edgesForExtendedLayout {
    return UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide status bar from a particular view add this method in that particular  `view.m` file

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: he doesn't, the map view is screwing things up for the op

Answer (score 1):

What about setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in viewDidLoad of your view controller or in IB?

Comment: see the question image the problem in iOS6. watch the navigation back button you understand which version the problem raised.

Comment: @iDev it is iOS 7 according to images and tags author specified. Back button is not from iOS 6 either as it is custom. Such problem on the other hand cannot basically happen on iOS 6 as it doesn't support extended edges.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to set MapView(ScrollView) automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
2. Try to set edgesForExtendedLayout to UIRectEdgeNone;
3. Try to use UIViewController.topLayoutGuide, see the Q&A from apple about this issue:[Preventing the Status Bar from Covering Your Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html).
4. Try to use the bar position delegation, see [UIBarPositioningDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarPositioningDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIBarPositioningDelegate/positionForBar%3a)

According to your description and screenshots, you are trying to move the whole UINavigationController.view.frame 20 pt, and the MapView(ScrollView) did something to prevent it happened (or re-set), put some breakpoint and log to track the frame of UINavigationController.view.frame changed.

Could you please provide a sample project? I'm so curious about what really happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
[application setStatusBarHidden:YES];
return YES;}
```

Please add this line to your code.This will ***hide*** the ***status bar*** from your app.

Comment: he isn't trying to hide the bar. the map view screws up his layout

Answer (score 0):

If you have a xib. Did you try to enabled Top Bar in simulated Metrics ?

[image]

Comment: doesn't really influence output. especially when programmatically adding a map view